# Why does tar complaint that it cannot find the file while extracting the archive?

Tags: tar

I uninstalled xampp and tried to reinstall it but when trying to extract it to the `/opt` directory, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo tar -xzf xampp-linux-1.8.3-2-installer.run.tar.gz -C /opt
tar (child): xampp-linux-1.8.3-2-installer.run.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now.
```

Why does tar complaint that it cannot find the file while extracting the archive?

Comment: did you inside the folder where tar.gz file is located?

Comment: Can you do `ls -l` in the dir where you run this command?

Comment: You change users (`sudo`) to a different person. That different person needs read rights on the tarball. Does that person (uid 0) have those rights?  (The usual answer is: Heck yes, toor/root/admin has those rights, but but SE linux that is no longer always true.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the dir in the terminal (identified by `pwd`) does not contain the archive that you're trying to unpack. You need to `cd /path_to_archive_dir/`, and then execute the command there (`tar -xzf xampp-linux-1.8.3-2-installer.run.tar.gz -C /opt`).